# Is there a way to return all rows where only one column is not null?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I'd like to break up into logical sub-dataframes.

The most logical way to do this, given how the data is, is to select rows from the original dataframe where only one of the columns is not null (i.e. `df.column.notnull()` is `True`).

Is there a shorthand for this or do I need to check each *other* column for every column that is not null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a mask using `.sum(axis=1)` on the result of `df.notnull()` and checking if equal to 1:

```
df[df.notnull().sum(axis=1).eq(1)]
```

With some sample data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': [1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
     'B': [np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan],
     'C': [np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan],
     'D': [np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan]}
)
df[df.notnull().sum(axis=1).eq(1)]
```

returns

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1.0 NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 2.0 NaN NaN
```

from the original DataFrame

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1.0 NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 2.0 NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN 3.0 4.0
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```